# Code to open video in videoView from android phone storage

Tags: android

I have been modifying an example video player code; the example code played the video from the program resource directory. I copied the video to the phone's /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ directory and add three lines:

String videoName1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/DCIM/steprock";

Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoName1);

videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

to replace:

videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.steprock));

This change causes a file not found error. The video is in the Phone storage DCIM directory. I also tried adding the .mp4 to the video name.

In debug mode the uri appears to be the correct value: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/steprock

Can anyone spot the code error? A partial listing is below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    String videoName1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/DCIM/steprock";
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoName1);
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    //videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.steprock));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, forgot to add the read permission below to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<application ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is code which play video from path you describe for video in VideoView.

```
// Video path.
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/DCIM/steprock.mp4";
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```